# Can I tell what graphic engine an Android game uses?

Tags: android, graphics, graphic-effects

How can I know which graphic engine has an app android game like "Hidden City" for example?

Are there any tools or web pages to analyse some game applications for android to know how they did the graphics in their game?

For example if developers used some engine or pure XML?

PD: I don't want to steal the graphics, I just want to know how they managed to get that graphics in their game.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. You can use the same engine in very different ways to achieve very different visuals. You should ask how to achieve a particular effect with a particular engine instead.

Comment: Agreed; while I think your question is technically on-topic here, I don't think the answer is really going to be that helpful for you. If you're _actually_ interested in how to get a particular style or effect, you should just ask a new question about how to actually obtain that effect. Often doing so requires more than just "the engine," it also requires some amount of technique to be applied somewhere -- in the authoring of the art, or the materials, or the code, for example.

Comment: This is such a weird question because all games use the same underlying low level tech. Whether the high level stuff is purely data driven or not eventually doesn't matter to the final product. You can get the same results in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i know which graphic engine has an app android game like "Hidden City" for example?

In some cases, a developer will state the technology they use. Perhaps casually, in interviews or Twitter, or perhaps somewhere in the credits due to legal licensing requirements.

In other cases you may be able to make educated guesses based on how the technology looks or behaves, assuming the technology was used mostly-unmodified and *has* some distinctive characteristics you can look for.

You also may be able to tell through inspection of the game's binaries or data files, if possible.

But in general, you can't just go to some registry website and look the game up and get an answer. Your best bet, if you are curious, is to attempt to get in touch with the developer and ask if research does not reveal the answer elsewhere.